# capture android device screenshot with adb & perl

Tags: android, windows, perl, adb, screenshot

I tried the one liner solution to capture screenshot via adb and the file is created successfully on PC but it is unreadable:

```
 C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > c:\users\utilisateur\desktop\android_screenshot1.png
```

[image]

The file seem to be correct but I think the Magic is not correct:
[image]

**EDIT:** The same issue happened with Git Bash for Windows.

Comment: @AlexP. it doesn't work! sorry!

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong. It produces valid `PNG` files on my system. As does `sed` - `adb shell screencap -p | sed "s/\r\r$//g" > test.png`

Comment: also try `perl -pe "binmode(STDOUT);s/\r\n/\n/g"`

Comment: @AlexP.: Same error; P.S: I am using Strawberry Perl (64-bit) 5.20.2.1-64bit on Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64 and latest Android SDK.

Comment: When using **screencap -p /sdcard/xxx.png** it works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > screen.png
```

will save it on your machine directly

Comment: Thanks, shortest answer so far!

Comment: awesome.. that wored

Answer (score 4):

@Passella [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31295050/474031) worked for me with a little tweaking:

```
adb shell screencap -p "/mnt/sdcard/output.png" && adb pull "/mnt/sdcard/output.png" "C:\output.png" && adb shell rm "/mnt/sdcard/output.png"
```

I had to quote the paths and replace `|` with `&&`.

Also, if you are using a `Genymotion` simulator, it's better to use its own `adb`:

```
C:\"Program Files"\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb shell screencap -p "/mnt/sdcard/output.png" && C:\"Program Files"\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb pull "/mnt/sdcard/output.png" "C:\output.png" && C:\"Program Files"\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb shell rm "/mnt/sdcard/output.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
adb shell screencap -p /mnt/sdcard/output.png | adb pull /mnt/sdcard/output.png C:\output.png | adb shell rm /mnt/sdcard/output.png
```